# Error clicking on Locked Media Library item: Failed to map the path '/temp/_disabled.'

Tags: sitecore-client

I get the following error when I click on an item which is locked by another user inside the media library in Sitecore. We recently upgraded from Sitecore 7.2 to Sitecore 9.

Stack Trace:

```
[HttpException (0x80004005): Failed to map the path '/temp/_disabled.'.]
   System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.MapPathCaching(String siteID, VirtualPath path) +1287
   System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPath2.MapPath(String siteID, VirtualPath path) +9
   System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull) +869
   System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping) +151
   System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path) +101
   Sitecore.Resources.Themes.GetFilename(String source, String size, String overlay, Boolean disabled) +262
   Sitecore.Resources.Themes.Transform(String source, String overlay, Boolean disabled) +318
   Sitecore.Resources.Themes.MapTheme(String sourcePath, String overlay, Boolean disabled) +144
   Sitecore.Resources.ImageBuilder.ToString() +352
   Sitecore.Shell.Web.UI.WebControls.SmallGalleryButton.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +547
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +132
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderSmallButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Control smallButton) +118
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderSmallGalleryButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext) +953
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext) +760
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext) +342
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual, String id) +244
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunk(HtmlTextWriter output, Item chunk, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual) +161
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderChunks(HtmlTextWriter output, Item strip, CommandContext commandContext, Boolean isContextual) +426
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter output, Item ribbon, Boolean isContextual, ListString visibleStripList) +1613
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderStrips(HtmlTextWriter output, Item defaultRibbon, Item contextualRibbon, ListString visibleStripList) +162
   Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.Render(HtmlTextWriter output) +734
   System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter) +132
   Sitecore.Web.HtmlUtil.RenderControl(Control ctl) +80
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.UpdateRibbon(Item folder, Boolean isCurrentItemChanged, Boolean showEditor) +560
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.Update() +582
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorForm.OnPreRendered(EventArgs e) +205

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation.]
   System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor) +0
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.UnsafeInvokeInternal(Object obj, Object[] parameters, Object[] arguments) +128
   System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture) +142
   Sitecore.Reflection.ReflectionUtil.InvokeMethod(MethodInfo method, Object[] parameters, Object obj) +89
   Sitecore.Shell.Applications.ContentManager.ContentEditorPage.OnPreRender(EventArgs e) +143
   System.Web.UI.Control.PreRenderRecursiveInternal() +200
   System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +7479
```

Any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance !

Screenshot of the same is below.

[image: Popup with Error: Failed to map the path '/temp/disabled.'.]

Comment: It's only a guess but do you have `/temp` folder in your website root? Can the app pool user access / modify that folder and its content?

Comment: Thanks for the reply ! Yes, app pool user has read write access to the folder.

Answer (score 2):

There is a support patch for this issue. It seems to happen for my instance (8.2.7) while the selected media item is locked by a different user.

https://github.com/SitecoreSupport/Sitecore.Support.212651/releases

Example message logged:

> Exception: System.Web.HttpException
>   Message: Failed to map the path '/temp/_disabled.'.
>   Source: System.Web
>      at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.MapPathCaching(String siteID, VirtualPath path)
>      at System.Web.Configuration.ProcessHostMapPath.System.Web.Configuration.IConfigMapPath2.MapPath(String siteID, VirtualPath path)
>      at System.Web.Hosting.HostingEnvironment.MapPathActual(VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean permitNull)
>      at System.Web.HttpRequest.MapPath(VirtualPath virtualPath, VirtualPath baseVirtualDir, Boolean allowCrossAppMapping)
>      at System.Web.HttpServerUtility.MapPath(String path)
>      at Sitecore.Resources.Themes.GetFilename(String source, String size, String overlay, Boolean disabled)
>      at Sitecore.Resources.Themes.Transform(String source, String overlay, Boolean disabled)
>      at Sitecore.Resources.Themes.MapTheme(String sourcePath, String overlay, Boolean disabled)
>      at Sitecore.Resources.ImageBuilder.ToString()
>      at Sitecore.Shell.Web.UI.WebControls.SmallGalleryButton.Render(HtmlTextWriter output)
>      at System.Web.UI.Control.RenderControlInternal(HtmlTextWriter writer, ControlAdapter adapter)
>      at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderSmallButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Control smallButton)
>      at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderSmallGalleryButton(HtmlTextWriter output, Item button, CommandContext commandContext)
>      at Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Ribbons.Ribbon.RenderButton(HtmlTextWriter ...

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before. When an image, e.g. MyBtnImage.png, is specified for a ribbon button, Sitecore also creates temporary alternate image files e.g. /temp/MyBtnImage_disabled.png.

These ribbon button definitions are in the Core DB, I don't remember the exact path right now. I speculate that if a button definition has a missing/invalid image field, Sitecore creates this invalid "/temp/_disabled." path (note the ".", which makes it an invalid path!).

So, I guess one of your ribbon buttons has an invalid image field. You could try removing displayed ribbon chunks and buttons to narrow down which one is choking.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to do exactly the same but it's taking time to narrow down to the culprit.